# Using Parsec for lexing&parsing

Tags: haskell, parsing, parsec

I'm creating list of `Token`s from input `[Char]` stream using Parsec v3. The definition of `Token` looks like this:

```
data Token = CharKeyword | OpeningBracket | Identifier String | Natural Int
```

As result of calling `parse lexComb "" inputStream` i have `[Token]`. Everything OK so far.

Now i want to parse this list of tokens using another `parse` invocation, but i've found myself writing such boilerplate code for every `Token` constructor:

```
psOpBracket = tokenPrim s np p
    where
        s _ = "'{'"
        p (OpeningBracket) = Just Nothing
        p _ = Nothing
        np pos _ _  = pos
```

another example:

```
psPacketName = tokenPrim s np p
    where
        s x = x
        p (Identifier x) = Just x
        p _ = Nothing
        np pos _ _  = pos
```

I wonder if it's right to use tokenPrim at all. And if so, is there any way to automatically generate parsers for every token? Maybe Template Haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by using `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.GeneralizedToken` from [MissingH](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.1.1.0) package:

```
psOpBracket = tokeng (\x -> case x of TokOpBracket -> Just Nothing ; _ -> Nothing)
```

I had to use `tokenPrim` for cases when `Token` constructor takes arguments, though.